# Etymology of "modal dialogs" in computerese

Tags: etymology, adjectives, computing

When programming you may deal with so-called *modal dialogs* — these are windows where you are supposed to provide information before you are allowed to proceed any further. A modal dialog blocks or dims the rest of user interface (UI) until you dismiss the dialog via Cancel or OK-type of a button.

But what's bugging me is — why actually the "modal" adjective is used to name this part of interface?

Comment: Simply put, a *modal* dialog box takes focus and does not let the user continue with the task until it is dismissed. The other kind of dialog boxes are *modeless*, that is they do not force the user into a 'mode' (of control by the dialog box).

Comment: Did you look it up? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28computer_interface%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good explanation from mjv on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607783/why-is-a-modal-modeless-dialog-called-modal-modeless):

> With a modal dialog, you set your application in a particular ***mode*** (a different "state" if you will), whereby only actions pertaining to that "mode" are accepted, hence preventing UI actions outside of the dialog.
>
> At Andreas' prompting I thought I may have to dig dusty Windows API books, as often, the etymology/origin of a word or expression that has became broadly accepted is only found in early documentation, but in fact we still see this referenced in [**an online glossary from MS**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511441.aspx#M).  The Modal entry reads (emphasis is mine):
>   **modal**
>   Restrictive or limited interaction *due to operating in a mode*. Modal often describes a secondary window that restricts a user's interaction with the owner window. See also: modeless.

Here's the full [FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/modal) entry:

> (Of an interface) Having modes. Modeless interfaces are generally considered to be superior
>   because the user does not have to remember
>   which mode he is in.
>
> 2. See modal logic.
> 3. In MS Windows programming, A window with the label "WS_MODAL" will stay on the screen and
>      claim all the user-input. Other windows can only
>      be accessed if the MODAL window is closed. Such
>      a window would typically be used for an error dialog box to warn the user for something important, like "Critical error, shut down the
>      system and restart".

The [Jargon File](http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/M/mode.html) (version 4.4.7) defines the noun *mode*:

> [common] A general state, usually used with an
>   adjective describing the state. Use of the word
>   ‘mode’ rather than ‘state’ implies that the state
>   is extended over time, and probably also that
>   some activity characteristic of that state is being
>   carried out. “No time to hack; I'm in thesis mode.” In its jargon sense, ‘mode’ is most often
>   attributed to people, though it is sometimes
>   applied to programs and inanimate objects. In
>   particular, see hack mode, day mode, night mode, demo mode, fireworks mode, and yoyo mode; also talk mode.
>
> One also often hears the verbs enable and
>   disable used in connection with jargon modes.
>   Thus, for example, a sillier way of saying “I'm
>   going to crash” is “I'm going to enable crash
>   mode now”. One might also hear a request to
>   “disable flame mode, please”.
>
> In a usage much closer to techspeak, a mode is
>   a special state that certain user interfaces must
>   pass into in order to perform certain functions.
>   For example, in order to insert characters into a
>   document in the Unix editor vi, one must type the “i” key, which invokes the “Insert”
>   command. The effect of this command is to put
>   vi into “insert mode”, in which typing the “i” key
>   has a quite different effect (to wit, it inserts an
>   “i” into the document). One must then hit
>   another special key, “ESC”, in order to leave “insert mode”. Nowadays, modeful interfaces
>   are generally considered losing but survive in quite a few widely used tools built in less
>   enlightened times.

Comment: Thank. I have encountered this term for the first time back in the end of 1990's when I was programming applications for my Macintosh. Now I see it used to refer to web pages UI where layers have this modal behavior.

Comment: In fact "modal dialog" was present from the beginning of Mac programming (goes back to the 1980's).

Comment: Great examples, but I am not convinced that 'mode' is the source. It feels like a folk etymology (the first example). The UX of a modal dialog, as opposed to a modeless interface, is that of forcing one down a particular path; you -have- to attend to the dialog rather than choose to ignore it. And this concept of 'necessity' or 'must' is considered a 'modal' quality.

Comment: Agreed @mitch - a modal verb expresses a possibility which is what the question is doing. Seems likely related.