# What is the origin of the term "modal" when it qualifies a dialoxbox or a window?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Computers documentation often refers to [modal windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) or [dialog box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_box).

The meaning is clear : a modal element (window or dialog box) disables user interaction with the main window, but keeps it visible, with the modal element in front of it.

However, I never understood the origin of the term "modal" to qualify this behavior.

What is the origin of this adjective in User Interface context ?

*Edit:*
The question is certainly a duplicate with [Q1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103192/etymology-of-modal-dialogs-in-computerese) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607783/why-is-a-modal-modeless-dialog-called-modal-modeless)

But, the answers are similar to that of @YosefBaskin, i.e. "modal means what mode are you in? Stuck inside a dialog box or free to roam.".

According to these answers , "modal" is an antonym of "functioning in normal/standard/usual mode". But, may one understand "modal execution" instead of "safe mode execution" ?

Comment: Cross-site [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607813/1227152)

Answer (score -1):

From UX Planet:

[Modal and Non-Modal Screens](https://uxplanet.org/modality-the-one-ux-concept-you-need-to-understand-when-designing-intuitive-user-interfaces-e5e941c7acb1).

> The main difference lies in the way you can interact with each screen. While a Non-Modal Screen allows users to simply go back to the parent screen, the Modal Screen requires users to complete an action before returning to the main window (“save” in our example) or cancel the current action.

I take it modal means what mode are you in? Stuck inside a dialog box or free to roam?